# IIS php header 404 call won't use deafult error page

Tags: php, iis, http-headers

When I run `header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');`, IIS 8.5 (on Windows Server 2012r2 with php 5.6.31) just shows a blank page. However, the page header reports a 404 status code. What can I do to make IIS display the default error page that is sent when a page doesn't actually exist?

Comment: I also tried `header('Status: 404 Not Found');` and `http_response_code(404);` with no luck

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. In web.config, under:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
```

Add the line:

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" />
```

More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/httpErrors/#attributes